# I can't get a return from flutterfire realtime database emulator?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

I have already done everything for the setup I'm sure. I connected my project in the firebase console, and I was able to get my app to run after an await firebase initialize (options : options...etc.) once I finished with the flutterfire CLI config.

But now I can't get the actual value from my json file in the realtime database emulator. All I can get is null. Maybe I am not referring to the json right, but my json right now is just:
{ "hello" : "hi" }
so I don't think that's the problem. This is how I'm calling the database.

```
final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
```

and I'm using a future builder.

```
  child:FutureBuilder(
                future: _database.child('http://{$host_number}/?ns=nimble-autumn-{$project_id_number}/hello').get(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    return ListView.builder(
    //shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: gocrazy.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return PostCard(
    status: public[0], comments: [snapshot.toString()]);
    //rags[index]);
    },
    );
    }
    else {

    return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
    Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
    child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
    ),
    ]
    );
    };
```

And the UI will complete with the if statement because I am using .toString() and this what I get (if I use .value it will cause null error).
It says invalid Firebase Database data path. So what is the valid way to put it? I am using:
'http://{$host_number}/?ns=nimble-autumn-{$projectid}/hello'
but using 'nimble-autumn-projectid/hello' or 'hello' will just have the futurebuilder hang indefinitely.

Comment: check if something else is wrong with your code, cuz simply putting `child('hello')` should work

Comment: this is how I'm connecting to the realtime database after the main() {await firebase....} and I just commented this line out and it didn't make a difference so I think it's wrong: FirebaseDatabase.instance.useDatabaseEmulator('localhost', 9199);